# Is there an equivalent of while(scanf()==1) in java?

Tags: java

I have been using the following code in c and c++ for looping till user feeds the correct value till the program comes out of it:

```
while((scanf("%d",&num)==1)//same way in for loop
{
  //some code
}
```

Can i some how use the same way to accept and loop the program till i keep entering let's say an integer and floating or a char or a special character breaks it.

Comment: How are you planning to read data?. Have you looked at the methods in that class ?

Comment: Have a look at the class "Scanner" : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle: yeah, i stopped reading the while thing when i came to the solution i needed. Thanks

Comment: @TheLostMind: Its just a simple program of accepting the integers till some other input other than integer is given. PS... I m a rookie here, just started java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // OR replace System.in with file to read
while(sc.hasNext()){
   //code here
   int x = sc.nextInt();
   //...
}
```

There are different variants of `hasNext()` for specific expected input types: `hasNextFloat()`, `hasNextInt()`..
 Same goes for `next()` method so you can find `nextInt()`, `nextFloat()` or even `nextLine()`

You can go to [Java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()) for more info.

Comment: Thanks. Lot of statements as compared to c and c++ for doing one thing, but hey who's asking.

Answer (score 0):

As proposed in comments, you can use the `Scanner` class.
Note you need to read the in buffer with a `nextLine()` when it is not an `int`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.println("Enter an int: ");
        while (!in.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("That's not an int! try again...");
            in.nextLine();
        }
        int myInt = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You entered "+myInt);
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to mention java.util.Scanner class, but i guess that's okay. I cant be spoon fed. But is using try() method necessary, the above example works just fine

Comment: The `try (...) {...}` (called [try with resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)) is just there to automatically `close()` the `Scanner` when you are done with it. This is good practice to close any resource like files, connections, etc. You can also do it explicitly in your code and manage the different exceptions.

Comment: So that is why i keep getting the warnings for memory leaks is it? I use @SuppressWarnings("resource") to close this in main.

Comment: Yes. As said, you should close the resource rather than adding the @SupressWarning.